How to prove $ax+by\equiv c\pmod{n}$ has a solution if and only if $gcd(a,b,n)\mid c$?
How to prove $ax+by\equiv c\pmod{n}$ has a solution if and only if $gcd(a,b,n)\mid c$?

Proof.
($\implies$) Because $ax+by-c=kn$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$ax+by-kn=c$$
If $x_0$ and $y_0$ are solutions for the linear congruence,
$$ax_0+by_0-kn=c$$
Let $d=\gcd(a,b,n)$. Then there exist integers $r,s$ and $t$ such that $a=dr,b=ds,n=dt$. So,
$$drx_0+dsy_0-dtk=d(rx_0+sy_0-tk)=c$$
Therefore, $d\mid c$.

Question: I could only attempt to prove the 'only if' part. The part can be proved as above. But i am stuck at 'if' part. How can I prove the 'if' part?

What i tried for the 'if' part:
I started from the point that since $gcd(a,b,n)|c$, for some integers $a',b',n'$ and $c'$,
$$a=da', b=db', n=dn', c=dc'$$
where $\gcd(a',b',n')=1$. Therefore
$$ax+by\equiv c\pmod{n}\implies a'x+b'y\equiv c'\pmod{n'}$$
If $\gcd(a',b')=1$ holds(NOT TRUE), then $a'x+b'y=1$ holds for some integers $x=x_0$ and $y=y_0$. So, we could multiply both sides of it by $c'$ to yield
$$a'(c'x_0)+b'(c'y_0)=c'$$

According to Bézout's identity, there exist three integers $x_1, x_2, x_3$ such that
$
a x_1 + b x_2 + n x_3 = d
$
We know that $c = d e$ for some integer $e$. Hence
$ a e x_1 + b e x_2 + n e x_3 = c $
If we define $x = e x_1$ and $y = e x_2$ we get
$a x + b y \equiv c \pmod{n}$

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
